# How can I remove tomcat 9 installation from my ubuntu 18.04 machine?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04, tomcat9

What commands must I run so that I can unistall tomcat9 and install tomcat8.
The reason I am doing this is that I cannot get fuseki.war to run as application. I get

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/fuseki] could not be started
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Remove tomcat**

To remove system and config files from Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt remove --purge tomcat9 tomcat9-docs
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Locate and remove manually the remaining files if there are some

```
sudo apt install locate && sudo updatedb
locate tomcat
```

**2. Install apache Jena fuseki**

```
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-fuseki-3.8.0.tar.gz
cd /opt
sudo tar xzf ~/apache-jena-fuseki-3.8.0.tar.gz
sudo ln -s apache-jena-fuseki-3.8.0 fuseki
```

Create fuseki user

```
sudo adduser --system --home /opt/fuseki --no-create-home fuseki
```

For install we follow the « Filesystem Hierarchy Standard »:

- code in `/opt/fuseki
- database in /var/lib/fuseki
- logs in /var/log/fuseki
- config files in /etc/fuseki

In `/var/lib` folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p fuseki/{backups,databases,system,system_files}
sudo chown -R fuseki fuseki
cd /var/log
sudo mkdir fuseki
sudo chown fuseki fuseki
cd /etc
sudo mkdir fuseki
sudo chown fuseki fuseki
cd /etc/fuseki
sudo ln -s /var/lib/fuseki/* .
sudo ln -s /var/log/fuseki logs
```

Create the service

edit in /etc/default/fuseki:

> FUSEKI_HOME=/opt/fuseki
>
> FUSEKI_BASE=/etc/fuseki
>
> FUSEKI_USER=fuseki
>
> JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048M"

Create symlink in `init.d`:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo ln -s /opt/fuseki/fuseki .
```

Start the service

```
sudo service fuseki start
sudo update-rc.d fuseki defaults
```